# .htaccess - 301 redirect all files without extension to have .html extension

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to 301 redirect requests to files with no extension to same with appended .html extension:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/this
```

to

```
http://www.mydomain.com/this.html
```

The following would not get redirected:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/that/ (it's a directory)
http://www.mydomain.com/other.php
```

Any help appreciated on the above, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following. I would place it as the last rule in your set (i.e. the bottom) to not conflict with any other rules.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.html [R=301,L]
```

This should ensure the request is not a directory and that is doesn't end with *some kind of extension*. If those conditions are met, it will append the request with `.html`.

This is untested, so comment back if it works. ;)

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks, although I did have to place at top of htaccess rules list.

Comment: Good. Yeah, without seeing all your rules I took a guess. It's typically best to place this at the top or bottom. I normally go with bottom.