# How to set .html extension in pages in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I'm facing problems with Wordpress's permalink structure, with a set custom structure : %postname%. I want to display the page as page.html... I've used html on pages plugins for that.  It is working on the local server but not working on the live server.
Any Ideas?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4337727/614152

Comment: already use in .htaccess file. bt not getting view i needed.  without plugins change permalink for .html extension in pages?

Comment: I have used this Plugin [WP Page Extension](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-page-extension/) for changing the post and page's extension to .html. It is working fine in my live server. Also it is working fine with Latest WP Version 3.8 (Current Latest Version)